# View created dynamically not responding to OnClickListener

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I have a view called `EventListSmallView` and `FollowerFollowingView` that extends RelativeLayout and are created dynamically in my activities.

The problem is:
If i set onClickListener for the `FollowerFollowingView`it works perfectly, but when i try to use with `EventListSmallView` it doesn't work.

Thats how i set each one:
- EventListSmallView

```
for (Event event : eventsGo){
            final Event e = event;
            EventListSmallView eventListSmallView = EventListSmallView_.build(this);
            eventListSmallView.bind(event);
            eventListSmallView.setClickable(true);
            eventListSmallView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String json = new Gson().toJson(e);
                    EventDetailActivity_.intent(ProfileActivity.this)
                            .extra("json", json).start();
//                    Intent it = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, EventDetailActivity_.class);
//                    it.putExtra("json", json);
//                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });

            dynamicGo.addView(eventListSmallView);
        }
```

and FollowerFollowingView:

```
FollowerFollowingView itemView = FollowerFollowingView_.build(this);
        itemView.bind(p);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String json = new Gson().toJson(profile);
                if (profile.getId() == Config.getMyID(getApplicationContext())){
                    ProfileActivity_.intent(EventDetailActivity.this)
                            .extra("serialized_profile", json).extra("is_user",true).start();
                }else {
                    ProfileActivity_.intent(EventDetailActivity.this)
                            .extra("serialized_profile", json)
                            .start();
                }
            }
        });
        whoGoing.addView(itemView);
```

Comment: Seems you are adding views in for loop and there are no ID for each of them at all. So if you add 10 views, how does it distinguish which view has been clicked?

Comment: Because im setting an OnClickListener for each one? '-'

Comment: But lets assume that you are correct...in the `FollowerFollowingView` im using a for too. The difference its inside the for i call a method that contains the code showed above. Why the click works on that?